# Under what circumstances would SUSER_SNAME return an AD group name rather than the user name?

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server, I have a trigger that uses SUSER_SNAME to record the user name.

This seems to work fine except in one case where a user is reporting that, for them, it records an Active Directory group name, rather than the actual user. I'm having trouble reproducing the behaviour.

Can anyone tell me under what circumstances SUSER_SNAME will return an AD group rather than a specific username?

Comment: How is the user in question authenticating to the instance? You can create a `LOGIN` for an AD Group, and then *all* users in that group can authenticate to the instance, even if they don't have an explicit `LOGIN` for their AD User. I suspect that would be the scenario that would cause the user to get such behaviour.

Comment: That was my guess too. If I configure SQL Server such that I'm allowed to connect due to my membership of an AD group, rather than a specific AD user, SUSER_SNAME still reports my AD user name, rather than the group that gave me access.

Comment: Indeed, I cannot replicate it either

Comment: I just tested in a sandbox environment as well, and used `SELECT SUSER_SNAME({SID})` (where `{SID}` is the SID of a Windows users that is in an AD Group with a `LOGIN` but *not* an AD User `LOGIN`) and I too got their username, not the Group's name.

Comment: Dumb question, is the user mistaken? :) You say the user has reported this has happened, but have you actually verified it *did* happen?

Comment: I have seen the behaviour demonstrated, yes.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does sys.login_token show for this user?